# Finding a latest folder that contains a specific file

Tags: batch-file, scripting, batch-processing

I need to search a directory with multiple folders and check for the latest file(.exe) and copy that to another location.

```
SET "src_root"
SET "tgt_path"
DIR "%src_root%" /B /AD /O-D /TC > "%TEMP%\dirlist.tmp"
< "%TEMP%\dirlist.tmp" SET /P last_dir=
XCOPY "%src_root%\%last_dir%\*.exe" "%tgt_path%"**
```

This code helps me copy the EXE file in the latest folder, but in case, there is no EXE in the latest folder, I need to copy it from the folder which contains the latest EXE, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Ohh, I must be tired. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "filename="

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\neo.7z" '
 ) DO SET "filename=%%a"&set "dirname=%%~dpa"&goto found1

ECHO NOT found!
GOTO :eof

:found1
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\neo.7z" '
 ) DO IF /i "%dirname%" neq "%%~dpa" FOR /f %%s IN ('XCOPY /y /L /D "%filename%" "%%~dpa"') DO IF "%%s"=="0" SET "filename=%%a"&set "dirname=%%~dpa"&goto found1

ECHO latest file is "%filename%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used files named `neo.7z` for my testing - I believe that you should have a fixed filename in the situation you describe - the directories are no doubt not crammed with *.exe files.

It's very pedestrian, but will do the job.

Essentially, find any file with the required name in the required directory-tree and record the name in `filename`, directory in `dirname`.

Using that filename as a base, try `xcopy`ing it over every other matching filename. Use the `/L` flag to list-only, and the `/y` flag to remove user-intervention. If the return is `1 file(s) copied` ,f which only the first token is selected into `%%s`, then the chosen file is later. `0 file(s) copied` sets `%%s` to `0` and means that the chosen file is earlier, so select the newer file and directorynames and restart.

I'll leave it a a user-exercise to speed it up. (suggestions if interested : delayedexpansion, subroutine and retain-new-startpoint)

---

Revision [about 5 times faster]

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "filename="

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\neo.7z" '
 ) DO SET "candidate=%%a"&CALL :latest

ECHO latest file is "%filename%"
GOTO :eof

:latest
IF NOT DEFINED filename GOTO selectnew

FOR /f %%s IN ('XCOPY /y /L /D "%filename%" "%candidate%"') DO IF "%%s"=="1" goto :eof

:selectnew
SET "filename=%candidate%"

GOTO :EOF
```

This revision avoids the repetitive directory-scan. For each matching filename, compare the newly-found file against the previously-found file using the `xcopy /L` method, and select the new candidate if the new one is later. continue untill all matching names have been tested.

Comment: this works perfectly! but now i have a glitch, since my directory is too huge, the batch takes too much of a time finding the latest folder, any suggestion on how to tackle this?